# TCP/IP connection between IPad and IIS in c#

Tags: c#, iis-7, tcpclient

I want to implement a TCP/IP connection between my IIS and Ipad or Android device. For that I open a port in the IIS that always accept a connection from the device. If a connection is established between client and server then server holds the connection and responds to the device requests later. Because my requirement is when I have an update on the server I want to alert the device. Or if there is any alternative method available to identify the device. Please help me If you can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/). It's made for exactly this kind of scenario.